# Navbar collapse doesn't show up at 768px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `Bootstrap v3.3.6` and `jQuery v2.1.1`.
I wanna ask why my `navbar` didn't go to `nav collapse` in resolution `sm`?
Under resolution `width: 768px`, `nav collapse` shows up. But at `width: 768px` it didn't.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="people.html">People</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="inspiration.html">Inspiration</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="listJob.html">Jobs oportunity</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">hirring a chief?</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="signUp.html">login|signup</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Please tell me how to make `nav collapse` to show up in `min-width: 768px`?

Answer (score 1):

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Bootstrap Media Query defaults to LESS THAN 768px (so not including)

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */
```

This is why it works for less than 768px and not including.

The `sm` media query INCLUDES 768px and above.

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }
```

You can add your own media query to include the 768px

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { ... }
```

Comment: ngg, but i dont know the each attribute of navbar collpase